# Looking for easy script based gui framework that the output is closed exe

Tags: user-interface, scripting, frameworks

i need windows ( and linux latter on .. ) GUI framework that is based on scripting language ( doesn't matter which ) 
that the end result will be compiled native exe ( not relayed on installed script engine ) 
is there such beast ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[shoes](http://shoooes.net/) is very nice, cross-platfrom, written in ruby and allows to package programs as executables for win32, mac, linux.